# Images in Text Widget always on separate lines

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my personal website I am trying to put some small buttons that link to my other online profiles (linkedIn, StackOverflow etc.).

I have added html to a Text widget in the sidebar of my home page. And the buttons work as expected.

Where I am having trouble though is getting these buttons to all be on the same line - and I can't for the life of me figure out why they are on different lines.

The HTML code i use is:

```
<!-- LinkedIn Piece -->
<a href="https://nz.linkedin.com/pub/samuel-passmore/59/403/70a" style="text-decoration:none">
<img src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/webpromo/btn_in_20x15.png" width="30" height="22.5" border="0" style = "border-radius: 0em"></a>
<!-- StackOverflow Piece -->
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1544746/sampassmore" style="text-decoration:none;width: 30px">
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" width="30" height="22.5"></a>
```

And you can see the current result on my webpage
[www.sampassmore.com](http://www.sampassmore.com)

I think I have narrowed the issue down to the margins on the img tags, but setting them to 0px did not seem to do anything.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: try adding this `.textwidget {width: 600px;}
.textwidget > a {white-space: nowrap;}`

Comment: It's the `display` property of your `img` tag that's causing your problems.  It's set to `block` in your CSS.  Try changing it to `inline` (qualified by `.textwidget`, so you don't change the whole site)

Comment: @Adam Where is being added?

Comment: @Hobo that seemed to do it. Thank!

Comment: Cool; glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the 3 widgets then add a display: inline-block property. You need that property to change the size of a tags and to display them inline properly. For example:

```
a.social-icons {
    display: inline-block
}
```